# Get a vector of input variables' names out of "lm" and "glm" objects

Tags: r, glm, lm

I am trying to get the input variable names out of the model object returned by the `lm()` function. I tried to access the attribute 'variables' in under `lm_obj$terms`. However, the returned object is a 'language' type object rather than a regular vector of names.
For example:

```
lm_obj = lm(y ~ x + z + z:x, data=df)
attr(lm_obj$terms, 'variables')
# list(x, z)
```

What is a 'language' type? How to convert this 'language' type object to a regular vector like `c('x', 'z')`?

Answer (score 4):

**You are on the correct track. `"terms"` object is where you should look at.** If you want to omit the response variable, you can use `delete.response`.

```
all.vars(delete.response(terms(lm_obj)))
#[1] "x" "z"
```

I would also like to point you to

```
labels(terms(lm_obj))
#[1] "x"   "z"   "x:z"
```

which is sometimes more useful.

---

**A reproducible example to complement your question**

```
df <- data.frame(y = rnorm(20), x = rnorm(20), z = rnorm(20))
lm_obj <- lm(y ~ x + z + z:x, data = df)
```

---

**To see why we should look at "terms" than elsewhere**, you may try different answers here on the following model:

```
## thanks to user "WhatIf" for proposing `model = FALSE`
lmfit <- lm(y ~ poly(x) + z + I(z ^ 2) + z:x, data = df,
            na.action = na.exclude, model = FALSE)
rm(df)  ## do not omit this line! run it before trying other answers
```

---

**Misc Replies**

> (1) why does the 'variables' attribute store the 'language' object that spells out a list rather than a regular "list" object?

Because "terms" was created in an early stage of model fitting: formula parsing. Actual variable evaluation happens later.

> (2) how to convert a 'language' object to a regular "list" or "vector".

We do evaluation, where the quoted variables can be found:

```
eval(attr(terms(lm_obj), 'variables'), df)
```

Comment: Nice answer! Clean and no hacking. Gives reliable results in complicated cases. Inspired by your answer, I found that if we set `model = FALSE` in `lm()`, there will be no "model" component in the fitted model! Gosh, `lm()` has so many interesting arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You may get them out of the call,

```
fit <- lm(mpg ~ hp, mtcars)

head(all.vars(fit$call), -1)
# [1] "mpg" "hp"
```

or the `names` of the `model.frame` which is probably better.

```
names(model.frame(fit))
# [1] "mpg" "hp"
```

`"language"` is the (storage) `mode` or `typeof` of the object just as `"double"`, `"integer"` or `"list"` are. See `?mode`, for more explanation and nice examples. In the [R language definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-lang.html#Language-objects) you find a detailed explanation—anyway a nice reading.

#### Update

The `'variables'` attribute of the `terms` is such a `'language'` object.

```
(vars <- attr(fit$terms, 'variables'))
# list(mpg, hp, am)

typeof(vars)
# [1] "language"
```

To make use of it, we may coerce it `as.character` and remove the first element which is the name of the call, i.e. `'list'`,

```
as.character(vars)[-1]
# [1] "mpg" "hp"  "am"
```

or, it can be `eval`uated, what it might actually intended for. Obviously it only will work, if we state `with` which data object the information is available.

```
with(fit$model, eval(vars))
# [[1]]
#  [1] 21.0 21.0 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 17.8 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4
# [16] 10.4 14.7 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 27.3 26.0 30.4 15.8 19.7
# [31] 15.0 21.4
# 
# [[2]]
#  [1] 110 110  93 110 175 105 245  62  95 123 123 180 180 180 205 215 230  66
# [19]  52  65  97 150 150 245 175  66  91 113 264 175 335 109
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

If we ask *why* it isn't stored as a regular list, I would answer, because the information is already stored in the `fit$model`. It would be duplicated in a sense, and the size of the object would grow. The data is probably somewhere needed as list, the information itself actually is easier available using `fit$model`.

Comment: You solution worked out great. And thanks for explaining the 'language' object. But I am still confused on (1) why the 'variables' attribute stores the 'language' object that spells out a list rather than a regular list object (2) how to convert a 'language' object to a regular list or vector.

Comment: @PingPong Interesting questions, please see my update.

Answer (score 0):

In your object `m_obj$terms`, it is formula and you can access each term of it using `[[` extractor operator like

```
m_obj$terms[[1]]

#> `~`  # formula symbol
```

if you want to get your input variables you can use

```
strsplit(as.character(lm_obj$terms[[3]])[2] , " \\+ ")[[1]]

#> [1] "x" "z"
```